# Read XML-Content via Xcode for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, xcode, xml-parsing

I am trying to read a xml-file with,

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://www.link.com/xml.xml";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

in XCode (Objective-C) for an iphone-app, but my problem is, that even if that should work, it's not possible for me to get the content of that xml file visible or in a variable.

My Goal would be to get the text between every < tag > < / tag > and use this to get pictures out of the web via the link, and/or to write the text in the app.

The best and nearly only about that topic I found till now, which possibly could work is "http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/09/simple-xml-to-nsdictionary-converter/", but I am afraid that it's a little bit to complex for me.

I hope you can help me because I am searching all day long through the web and don't really get closer to my goal. Will be happy for everything.

Best regards
Chris

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the XML-file you want to parse really is XML-conform. Many files, which can be displayed by browsers are some kind of "messy" writen and can't be parsed easily with NSXMLparser.

If you have a XML-File that can be parsed, are you familiar with the delegate-driven way of NSXMLParser and did you already implement the

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName 
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict 
{... }
```

and

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
 didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName 
{ ... }
```

??

If yes, let me have a look at your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are parsing xmls in objective c and you are new to it.. your best bet is to use [TBXML](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html) library.

Its super easy and super fast!